# Aligning float captions in ConTeXt

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, context

This is my code:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\starttext
  Some Text

  \startcolumns[n=2]
    \placefigure[force] {First Figure} {
      \midaligned{

      \starttikzpicture
        \node[draw] {A};
      \stoptikzpicture
    }}
  \column
    \placefigure[force] {Second Figure} {
      \midaligned{

      \starttikzpicture
        \node[draw] (A) {A};
        \node[draw,below=of A] (B) {B};
        \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
      \stoptikzpicture
    }}
  \stopcolumns

  More Text
\stoptext
```

It outputs:

[image]

I would like to align the captions of the two floats. The left picture may move down together with the caption. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `floatcombination`.  I find it very convenient to use `\start...\stop` versions of all commands as you do not have to remember positional arguments (like for `\placefigure`).

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\starttext
Some Text

\startfloatcombination[distance=0pt]

  \startplacefigure[title={First Figure}]
    \startframed[frame=off,offset=none,width=.5\textwidth]
      \starttikzpicture
        \node[draw] {A};
      \stoptikzpicture
    \stopframed
  \stopplacefigure

  \startplacefigure[title={Second Figure}]
    \startframed[frame=off,offset=none,width=.5\textwidth]
      \starttikzpicture
        \node[draw] (A) {A};
        \node[draw,below=of A] (B) {B};
        \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
      \stoptikzpicture
    \stopframed
  \stopplacefigure

\stopfloatcombination

More Text
\stoptext
```

[image]